# Word for "seriously considering"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word like "pondering", of "considering" which has the connotation that I am very likely to decide to do the thing I am pondering/considering.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean in the idiomatic sense of *[increasingly] moving to a position of **accepting*** something? As opposed to the literal sense of *considering **in earnest** (not lightly)*, which doesn't necessarily carry any subtext of "likely to be selected". Idiomatically, we often say we're ***moving towards*** making [the choice we're "seriously considering"].

Comment: Leaning towards?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a single word (if one exists).

Comment: @Minnow It looks like an answer to me (in fact I wrote and posted it, having overlooked your comment; now deleted)

Comment: One term which has not, so far, been suggested is ***contemplating***. One of its meanings per the ODO is *have in view as a probable intention*. I am not sure if this provides the degree of settled intent that you have in mind.

Comment: The OP actually has three components 1) evaluation 2) probability 3) x-action. Each answer describes *either* 1) the evaluative process, or 2) the probability component of the OP. All synonymous terms for 1) the evaluative process (i.e., ponder, consider, contemplate, meditate) describe an *essentially neutral process* and do not address 2) the probability component. This is evident in the answers. Any response likely to satisfy the “*likely to decide*” aspect of OP will require the addition of a modifying adverb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be [inclined to](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/inclined):

> - wanting to do something or likely to do something
>
>   - I'm inclined to leave early!

(M -W)

Answer (score 3):

### Viable, widely used words

1. I will **likely** go to the circus. (Or, **probably**.)
2. I am **inclined** to accept the offer. ([Previously suggested](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/231367/103476) by Josh61.)
3. I **anticipate** buying the car.

The above words do not precisely fit your definition, however. "Likely" does not explain that you must ponder the issue. You wrote that you want the word to convey that you are "very likely" to select a specific option, but "inclined" is an imprecise word that could mean anything from "more likely than not" to "all but certain."

### Dialect specific word

In the American English sub-dialect used in the southern US, one of the senses of [**fixing to**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27391/etymology-of-fixing-to) precisely fits your meaning. Most people consider the phrase "improper English", but it exists because it serves a purpose that other words do not fulfill. To those who understand the term, "I'm fixing to give him a piece of my mind!" (plus the context of the statement) would certainly mean, "I have not fully resolved to talk to him, but it is highly likely [especially if the circumstances do not improve or if the circumstances worsen.]"

If there is an equivalent phrase in standard American English, I am unaware of it. Despite the utility of this phrase, I have rarely used it outside of the southern US (and Texas), and I only use it earnestly in spoken English and ironically or mockingly in some writings.

It's a shame, though. The [etymology of fix](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27391/etymology-of-fixing-to) shows that "fixing to" is a more natural use of the term than the modern meaning of "repair." A useful phrase banished by the so-called educated. *C'est la vie*.

Comment: Wouldn't 'I am inclined to' mean that I am not fully resolved (to do something) but it is highly likely that I will (do it)?

Comment: If inclined always means "highly likely" then phrases such as "highly inclined", "very inclined", or "slightly inclined" would be illogical.

Comment: 'inclined to' is generally used alone to suggest the idea that you are (very, highly) likely to do something: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=very+inclined+to%2Cslightly+inclined+to%2Cinclined+to%2C+highly+inclined+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvery%20inclined%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cslightly%20inclined%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinclined%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chighly%20inclined%20to%3B%2Cc0

Comment: _Fixing to_ is not native to me, but I have this feeling that it is only appropriate when the thing you're fixing to do is _positive_. For example, if someone's dog had terminal cancer, it would sound very strange to me if they said “We’re fixing to have him put down”. Or is that just me?

Comment: No, "fixing to" is a strong synonym for "preparing to," and similarly, it is used in many situations.

Comment: Also, to "fix" the local color, a native southerner would say, “We’re fi**tt**in' to have the dog put down”.

Answer (score 1):

As to *mull* wine bespeaks an intent or inclination to drink it, so to [*mull*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mull) an option may suggest an inclination to act upon it. OED identifies this sense of the verb *(v.<sup>4</sup>* 1.b.) as U.S.